# Can I set a users profile image using the Facebook API?

Tags: image, api, facebook, profile, photo

I'm looking for a `user.setImage` call or something to that effect on the [Facebook API](http://wiki.developers.facebook.com/index.php/API) but I can't see anything to achieve this: specifically to overwrite a user's profile image (not just post an image on their wall).

I can't see anything in the docs.  Do you know if this is possible and if so any docs on implementing it?

Comment: This is a duplicate of [How to set a Facebook profile picture using the Graph API](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4306786/how-to-set-a-facebook-profile-picture-using-the-graph-api/5431751#5431751), answered by [Fredrik](http://stackoverflow.com/users/87750/fredrik)

Comment: I know it's an old question, but it would be nice if you could mark as answered. Thanks!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to set a facebook profile picture using the graph api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4306786/how-to-set-a-facebook-profile-picture-using-the-graph-api)

Answer (score 41):

You can redirect the user to the following link where [PID] stands for the id of the desired picture:

```
http://www.facebook.com/photo.php?fbid=[PID]&makeprofile=1
```

On this page the user will see the picture and immediately be prompted with a dialog if he wants to set it as his profile picture.

Comment: great answer!!! i have 2 questions now: is there any posibility to avoid the cut-out-process (another parameter?) and do you have such a link for the title picture fanpages?

Comment: as far as i know there is no way to skip the cut-out-process. you should be able to change the cover photo of a page, just take a look at the documentation http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/page/ (search for "Setting a Cover Photo") - i didn't try it though.

Comment: but it wouldn't work if it is opened from mobile devices... the crop and set as profile pic button simply don't show up as if the makeprofile=1 param is ignored

Comment: this was working for me about a month ago, but it seems it no longer works. maybe they changed something.

Answer (score 13):

### No, you cannot.

From the [photos.Upload](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/rest/photos.upload/) documentation:

> However, you cannot upload to a user's
> profile picture album.

Answer (score 5):

Checkout my answer in this thread: [how to set a facebook profile picture using the graph api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4306786/how-to-set-a-facebook-profile-picture-using-the-graph-api/5431751#5431751)

You can't set the profile picture, but you can upload it to an album, and then send the user to the "make profile picture"-page for that picture.

Comment: If the question is a duplicate, you should add a link to the original in the comments section of the question.

Comment: Makes sense! Will do that next time!

Answer (score 3):

There must be a hidden API because the iphone facebook app does it...
Maybe you can discover how by setting a proxy between an iphone and Facebook and decipher it... or the API may be restricted to only Facebook's own apps...

Comment: The iPhone app authenticates with the users email & password, not via the Graph API.

Comment: I would hope that the API used to log you in is encrypted so your proxy won't help much, I think.

Answer (score 1):

Well it seems there's a way **now** with a new framework extension:
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/profile-expression-kit/ios#uploading

Answer (score 1):

You can upload an image, but you **CAN'T** set it as one's profile picture. So, the user has to set it as their profile picture themselves. You have to redirect them to the permalink of the uploaded image.

Comment: Doesn't https://stackoverflow.com/a/6309984/9731176 already say this?