# How can I alter profile images with a facebook application?

Tags: facebook

I would like to give my Facebook application users the ability to alter their profile picture with some predefined edits.  How can this be accomplished?

Comment: Just noticed, this is also a duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1648859/can-i-set-a-users-profile-image-using-the-facebook-api

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> You can upload to a specific user's
>   album by calling photos.getAlbums.
>   However, **you cannot upload to a user's
>   profile picture album**.