# Is it possible to edit Facebook user's profile through iPhone/iOS SDK?

Tags: iphone, facebook, profile

I am currently creating an App on iOS device (iPhone, iPod Touch).
Right now I can query user's profile data from Facebook and display them in my App.
I would like to edit user's profile data and update them back to Facebook.

Is there any method that can write the updated profile's data back to the facebook user's profile? I have spent a lot of time searching for this but cannot find a way.

Thank you very much.

Comment: Facebook has released its own app and IMO they dont provide this feature. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1648859/can-i-set-a-users-profile-image-using-the-facebook-api

Answer (score 1):

No, currently the Facebook for iPhone application does not support profile editing feature however you can post on walls.

**Note:-** I have asked a question about facebook api [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5012725/what-can-we-do-with-facebook-api-in-iphone-application).maybe you can get some answers there