# What can we do with facebook api in iphone application?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, facebook

I want to use facebook api in my iphone application. I know that we can **post to walls** with facebook api but i have no idea about other features like :-

- **edit profile**
- **send messages**
- **add friends**
- **get friends information** etc.

  So can anybody give me details about all the  things **we can or cannot do with facebook api** ?

Comment: Note: i can get more information about this on facebook but facebook is banned in my office

Comment: Then say to your company head to stop creating app on facebook .

Comment: Kainthia: If this is a company project, tell your bosses that you're going to need to access Facebook to work on it. If it's not a company project, you probably shouldn't be researching for it, working on it, or testing it at work (certainly not if they've banned Facebook).

Answer (score 1):

Here is a non-Facebook.com explanation of what the API can do:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Facebook_Platform

Comment: thanks very helpful but cover areas mostly other than my question

Answer (score 1):

Check out the Facebook-ios-sdk. 
The top level readme gives a good overview of the features.

https://github.com/facebook/facebook-ios-sdk