# Can i change Profile pic through iphone?

Tags: iphone

I want to change my profile pic through the iphone.Does Facebook provide any API which can change the Profile pic?Is it possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No its not possible

http://developers.facebook.com/search?q=Photos.upload

references:
[Can I set a users profile image using the Facebook API?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1648859/can-i-set-a-users-profile-image-using-the-facebook-api)