# Make image Facebook Cover

Tags: facebook-graph-api

Is there a way that after uploading an image from the application. I can allow the user to make it as his/her Facebook cover photo? (Directly or Indirectly)

Comment: are you talking about the profile picture? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1648859/can-i-set-a-users-profile-image-using-the-facebook-api

Comment: No - you can not change the cover photo with the API *yet*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no API which will allow this - you'll need the user to manually choose the photo to be their cover photo after you upload it to one of their existing albums